# Bounding Column's Values w/ Foreign Key Relationship?

Tags: foreign-key, rdbms

I'm creating a new table that contains a 'user'. So far, the table looks like:

```
create table users(
  id primary key,
  code varchar
)
```

Currently, the "universe" of codes consists of: `A` or `B`.

Is it worthwhile, from a DB Design point of view, to create a `codes` table that contains all known codes?

```
create table codes(
  value varchar, -- with unique constraint
  description varchar
)
```

Then, I could update my `users` table's `code` column to have a `foreign key` relationship to the `codes.table` column.

Does this change seem to be useful for my above case?

Comment: Do you expect the number of codes to grow with time? Is there additional data to be stored, in addition to the code? Having a `code` table makes sense from a user administration point of view (i.e., if users of a front-end app need to be able to add codes to the list), or if there's additional data to store. If those aren't issues, it might suffice to have a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the column, so its value must be 'A' or 'B'. Even then, there's nothing inherently wrong with a separate table and foreign key - you just have other options.

Comment: Yes, add the code table and foreign key.